# Space Complexity using "Constant reference to a variable"

Tags: c++, space-complexity

Here is my code that finds the indexes where the target variable exisits in a vector list.

```
vector<int> FindOccurences(string x, const vector<string> &num_vector)
{
    vector<int> occ;

    for (int i=0;i< num_vector.size() && num_vector.size() != 0  ; i++ )
    {
        if( num_vector[i] == x )
            occ.push_back(i);
    }

    return occ;
}
```

I want to know what would be the function's Space complexity. Since I'm using `const vector<string> &num_vector` there won't be any additional space used for this vector, right? Cause it would just access it where it was declared. But the `occ` vector can be of size `n`. Hence the space complexity would be O(n).

Is this correct?

Comment: You got it correctly - in the worst case when all strings in `num_vector` are equal to `x` the `occ` vector size will be equal to the size of `num_vector`.

Comment: `&& num_vector.size() != 0` is unnecessary. `0 < 0` is false so the loop would never be entered.

Comment: even if you would pass the vector by value it would still be only O(n). two times or three times O(n) is still O(n)

Comment: @Sameer is anything missing or unclear in my answer below ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are correct (assuming you were referring to worst case analysis).
The **worst case space complexity is O(n)**.

This will happen when O(n) of the entries in `num_vector` are equal to `x`, and then `occ` will have a size of O(n).

For example if 0.5 of the entries are equal to `x`, `occ` will have a size of 0.5n elements (which is in O(n)).